# ImportError: libcudart.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory* | I have cuda9.0 in my system and not cuda 8

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have cuda9.0 and tensorflow-gpu==1.5, while running a script I am getting below error.

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
        from lib.networks.factory import get_network
      File "/faster_rcnn/../lib/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        import fast_rcnn
      File "/faster_rcnn/../lib/fast_rcnn/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
        from . import train
      File "/faster_rcnn/../lib/fast_rcnn/train.py", line 15, in <module>
        from lib.fast_rcnn.nms_wrapper import nms_wrapper
      File "/faster_rcnn/../lib/fast_rcnn/nms_wrapper.py", line 10, in <module>
        from ..nms.gpu_nms import gpu_nms
    **ImportError: libcudart.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

[root@ ld.so.conf.d]# cat cuda-9-0.conf
/usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib
/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64
[root@ ld.so.conf.d]# pwd
/etc/ld.so.conf.d
[root@ ld.so.conf.d]# cat cuda-9-0.conf
/usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib
/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64


[root@ profile.d]# cat cuda90.sh
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}

[root@ lib64]# ls -ltr libcudart.*
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 442392 Sep  2  2017 libcudart.so.9.0.176
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     20 Jul 12 11:31 libcudart.so.9.0 -> libcudart.so.9.0.176
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     16 Jul 12 11:31 libcudart.so -> libcudart.so.9.0
```

I tried to check many posts and there are various flavors of answers but for the same cuda and libcudart issue, but in my case I have cuda 9 installed but its showing error for  libcudart.so.8.0:

Also, https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cuda-9-0-importerror-libcublas-so-8-0/54996 talks about compiling TF from source in 2017 but its almost 4 years and it should have work now.

Comment: Whatever you are using is clearly built against and has binary dependencies against CUDA 8.0. You have no choice but to use CUDA 8.0. Binary versioning is non-negotiable. You can't use a different version

Comment: Understood. This is what my assessment was. Let me go to the code and fix that,

Answer (score 0):

Particular version of Tensorflow is tested and configured with specific version of CUDA and cuDNN. In this case, Tensorflow version is demanding CUDA 8.0. Please take a look at the screenshot below for tested and build configuration.
[image]